# Snowflake copy into Non Ascii character Ú

Tags: python, export-to-csv

**File is being exported using below code. When we try to do a copy into in snowflake , we are having issue in loading the file to snowflake. What would be the delimiter here that can be used in file_format in snowflake.**

```
df_byte = df.to_csv(compression="gzip", 
     header=False,   
            index=False,   
            na_rep='NULL',  
            sep='Ú'    
            ).encode()
```

We have tried specifying hex values mentioned in snowflake documentation it didnt work.Please help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use ascii character (usually CSV is delimited by , or |)

For non-ASCII characters, you must use the hex byte sequence value to get a deterministic behavior. So, In your case, the field delimiter in the file format should be:
Hex values (prefixed by \x). For example, for records delimited by the Ú character, specify the hex (\xC3\x9A) value in the SNowflake FILE_FORMAT object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a multibyte character you need to use a hex value for it as in [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table):

Multibyte characters

```
Hex values (prefixed by \x). For example, for records delimited by the cent (¢) character, specify the hex (\xC2\xA2) value.
```

Setting the FIELD_DELIMITER = '\xC3\x9A' along with ENCODING='UTF-8' would allow the COPY INTO to load the data successfully.

To know the multibyte value of any character use:

```
select hex_encode('Ú');
```

Comment: Additionally we have the below issue raising for few files that has data enclosed as below '`' and we get this error. Any help on this? Error found character '`' instead of record delimiter '\n'

Comment: FIELD_DELIMITER ='\xC3\x9A',
    RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n',
    NULL_IF = 'NULL',
    REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE,
    ESCAPE = '\\',
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE,
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'

Comment: your enclose character is single quote or double quote?
as I see in first comment you mentioned ' ' but second comment FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"', if it's single quote you should provide.
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = ''''